# how to compare two pyspark dataframes?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to compare two spark data frames to find miss-match values from two data frame but I am getting only mismatched values of df1. I need to concatenate mismatched values of df1 and df2.

```
df1 = spark.read.load("df1.csv", format = "csv", header = "True")
df2 = spark.read.load("df2.csv", format = "csv", header = "True")
sss = df2.subtract(df1)
```

===================  df1 and df2  ====================
[image]

output from the code:

[image]

Expected Output Would be
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Columns col1, col2 and col3 are identical in expected output. Why do you need to include identical columns?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is indexed (has "id" column), you can join df2.subtract(df1) and df1.subtract(df2) on "id"

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                             (2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                             (3, 3, 3, 3, 3)], 
                             schema = ["id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                             (2, 2, 2, 2, 3),
                             (3, 3, 3 , 3, 4)], 
                             schema = ["id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

df_a = df1.subtract(df2)
df_b = df2.subtract(df1)
df = df_a.join(df_b, "id")
```

which produces the following df

[image]

If no index is available, it may not be possible to get Expected Output without additional requirements on matching column.

Comment: Thank you Anna k. it's giving correct results for my data, but I need to add one more column to trigger which columns have mismatched values.